# Traverse a list in reverse order in Python

Tags: python, loops, reverse

How do I traverse a list in reverse order in Python? So I can start from `collection[len(collection)-1]` and end in `collection[0]`.

I also want to be able to access the loop index.

Answer (score 1752, accepted):

Use the built-in [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> for i in reversed(a):
...     print(i)
... 
baz
bar
foo
```

To also access the original index, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) on your list before passing it to `reversed()`:

```
>>> for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(a))):
...     print(i, e)
... 
2 baz
1 bar
0 foo
```

Since `enumerate()` returns a generator and generators can't be reversed, you need to convert it to a `list` first.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, does this reversed method, creates a separate copy of the collection or just alters the looping?

Comment: No copy is created, the elements are reversed on the fly while traversing! This is an important feature of all these iteration functions (which all end on “ed”).

Comment: The reversed() function makes a copy of the collection. To modify an existing list, use the .reverse() method.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill No, it's an iterator over the original, no copy is created!

Comment: @André: you're right of course, but I was using the same words as the question asked by Joan, so that the answer would be more easily understood. Conceptually, it creates a copy. In implementation, it uses an iterator.

Comment: @Greg: Your new chunk of code to access the original index creates a second copy of the original collection. It would be better just to do something like i = len(a) - 1 - ridx

Comment: Kinda sucks that this has to traverse the entire list before iteration...  Still upvoted.

Comment: To avoid the confusion: `reversed()` doesn't modify the list. `reversed()` doesn't make a copy of the list (otherwise it would require O(N) additional memory). If you need to modify the list use `alist.reverse()`; if you need a copy of the list in reversed order use `alist[::-1]`.

Comment: in this answer though, list(enumerate(a)) DOES create a copy.

Comment: It doesn't quite make a copy, it seems to do the same logic as manually walking backwards.  If you call reversed, then alter the list, then iterate over the reversed list, the changes will be reflected by reversed().

Comment: It absolutely makes a copy of the list.  More accurately a zip of the list with it's positional indexes.

Comment: @Triptych: `reversed([a,b,c])` does *not* create a copy of `[a, b, c]`.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here about exactly which example we're discussing. The first example only uses reversed(); the second example uses reversed(list(enumerate())). Clearly the second example makes more copies than the first. I think you're all correct on some level. :)

Comment: @ JF, reversed() doesn't make a copy, but list(enumerate()) DOES make a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, but seems like there is confusion about how these methods are implemented. By copy I meant, a deep copy, not an iterator. Iterators are fine but deep copies would slow my code considerable, for several millions of data.

Comment: @Joan, you shouldn't be concerned with 'deep' versus 'shallow' copies.    That only matters when you're dealing with nested lists.  Even a 'shallow' copy will be expensive - it will duplicate the entire list. I believe my answer is the only one that matches your specs AND uses no extra memory.

Comment: Thanks Triptych, that's what I mean, not collection copy but an iterator copy.

Comment: Although `reversed(list(enumerate(a)))` works it's not optimized.  An alternative is proposed here using a lambda function: http://christophe-simonis-at-tiny.blogspot.ca/2008/08/python-reverse-enumerate.html

Comment: @Bill I think `enumerate(reversed(a))` would be also a solution. However, indices will be in reversed order i.e. the last element has index `0`

Comment: @Snowbunting, the indeces can be produces in reversed easily using `len(a)-i-1`, and if accessing a list `b` of the same length, `b[-i-1]` is equivalent to `b[len(a)-i-1]`

Comment: In fact, you can use the following generator `(-(ri+1), val) for ri, val in enumerate(reversed(foo))`, see my answer for example

Comment: I'd actually prefer @disooqi / Francsics version (`for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1)`) since this is one line and realy avoids any list-copying or list creation.

Comment: in most cases when you want to interate a list in reverse it's because elements might get deleted in the loop, this code doesn't solve that problem

Comment: No need for using a list(), you can use `enumerate(reversed(a))`, enumerate can handle generators

Answer (score 258):

You can do:

```
for item in my_list[::-1]:
    print item
```

(Or whatever you want to do in the for loop.)

The `[::-1]` slice reverses the list in the for loop (but won't actually modify your list "permanently").

Comment: `[::-1]` creates a shallow copy, therefore it doesn't change the array neither "permanently" nor "temporary".

Comment: This is slightly slower than using reversed, at least under Python 2.7 (tested).

Comment: **How this answer works**: it creates a sliced copy of the list with the parameters: *start point*: unspecified (becomes length of list so starts at end), *end point*: unspecified (becomes some magic number other than `0`, probably `-1`, so ends at start) and *step*: `-1` (iterates backwards through list, `1` item at a time).

Comment: I tested this as well (python 2.7) and it was ~10% slower to use [::-1] vs `reversed()`

Answer (score 130):

It can be done like this:

```
for i in range(len(collection)-1, -1, -1):
    print collection[i]

    # print(collection[i]) for python 3. +
```

So your guess was pretty close :) A little awkward but it's basically saying: start with 1 less than `len(collection)`, keep going until you get to just before -1, by steps of -1.

Fyi, the `help` function is very useful as it lets you view the docs for something from the Python console, eg:

`help(range)`

Comment: For versions of Python prior to 3.0, I believe xrange is preferable to range for large len(collection).

Comment: I believe you are correct :) iirc, range() generates the whole range as an array but xrange() returns an iterator that only generates the values as they are needed.

Comment: This just looks too weird with so many `-1`'s. I would just say `reversed(xrange(len(collection)))`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the argument values, I also like Barney Szabolcs solution which is based on the same backwards range iterator. Your explanation makes it easy to understand.

Comment: why the second -1 param? and not just 0?

Comment: @fayssalelansari you are exclusive on the upper bound with `range`

Comment: best answer for me, because it actually goes thru the list in reverse order, instead or somehow reversing the list wich won't do what the intended goal is of iterating a list in reverse !

Comment: `for i in range(start, end, width ) :` NOTE: while `start` is inclusive the `end` is not included . So for example, if `width=-1`(for reverse iteration) , and `start=len(collection)-1` then `end=-1` helps to iterate till the first element(index=0) of the collection. `end=0` will help iterate reversely upto index 1 of the collection (as index 0 should be excluded.

Answer (score 80):

If you need the loop index, and don't want to traverse the entire list twice, or use extra memory, I'd write a generator.

```
def reverse_enum(L):
   for index in reversed(xrange(len(L))):
      yield index, L[index]

L = ['foo', 'bar', 'bas']
for index, item in reverse_enum(L):
   print index, item
```

Comment: I would call the function enumerate_reversed, but that might be only my taste. I believe your answer is the cleanest for the specific question.

Comment: `reversed(xrange(len(L)))` produces the same indices as `xrange(len(L)-1, -1, -1)`.

Comment: @JF - yeah at the time I thought I had some reason for not doing it that way, but now I can't remember.  Changing it now.

Comment: This, but as a one-liner generator: ((i, sequence[i]) for i in reversed(xrange(len(sequence))))

Comment: I prefer fewer moving parts to understand: `for index, item in enumerate(reversed(L)): print len(L)-1-index, item`

Comment: @Triptych I just had to cope with fact that enumerate from reversed() won't yield reversed indexes, and your code helped a lot. This method should be in the standard library.

Comment: reversed() is not needed in this case. `xrange(len(L)-1, -1, -1)` should do the job. By the way, how come `reversed(xrange())` works but `reversed(enumerate())` doesn't?

Comment: reversed(xrange()) works because an xrange object has the \_\_reversed\_\_ method as well as the \_\_len\_\_ and \_\_getitem\_\_ methods, and reversed can detect that and use them.  But an enumerate object doesn't have \_\_reversed\_\_, \_\_len\_\_ or \_\_getitem\_\_.  But *why* doesn't enumerate have them?  I don't know that.

Comment: @FutureNerd because `enumerate` is a pure iterator object where as xrange is technically a sequece.  `iter(xrange(..))` however suffers the same restrictions that `enumerate` and any other iterator have.

Answer (score 48):

An approach with no imports:

```
for i in range(1,len(arr)+1):
    print(arr[-i])
```

Time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(1).

An approach that creates a new list in memory, be careful with large lists:

```
for i in arr[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

Time complexity O(n) and space complexity O(n).

Comment: This answer should be the top one, the first approach leaves the list intact, no copies are made and we are simply walking the indices backwards.  Very fast.  The second approach will create a new list so be aware.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my requirements. Thank you!

Answer (score 41):

The `reversed` builtin function is handy:

```
for item in reversed(sequence):
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed) for reversed explains its limitations.

For the cases where I have to walk a sequence in reverse along with the index (e.g. for in-place modifications changing the sequence length), I have this function defined an my codeutil module:

```
from six.moves import zip as izip, range as xrange

def reversed_enumerate(sequence):
    return izip(
        reversed(xrange(len(sequence))),
        reversed(sequence),
    )
```

This one avoids creating a copy of the sequence. Obviously, the `reversed` limitations still apply.

Answer (score 16):

Also, you could use either "range" or "count" functions. 
As follows:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    print(i, a[i])

3 baz
2 bar
1 foo
```

You could also use "count" from itertools as following:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
from itertools import count, takewhile

def larger_than_0(x):
    return x > 0

for x in takewhile(larger_than_0, count(3, -1)):
    print(x, a[x-1])

3 baz
2 bar
1 foo
```

Comment: The code in your first block there doesn't produce the right output; the output is actually `3 foo\n2 bar\n1 baz`

Comment: To avoid using "a[i-1]" in first example, use this range "range(len(a)-1, -1, -1)". This is more simplified.

Answer (score 15):

In python 3, list creates a copy, so `reversed(list(enumerate(collection))` could be inefficient, generating yet an other list is not optimized away.

If collection is a list for sure, then it may be best to hide the complexity behind an iterator

```
def reversed_enumerate(collection: list):
    for i in range(len(collection)-1, -1, -1):
        yield i, collection[i]
```

so, the cleanest is:

```
for i, elem in reversed_enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    print(i, elem)
```

Comment: this makes me cry

Comment: @CervEd You're absolutely right, it made me cry too when I came back. Updated my answer. -- although range makes me still cry a bit...

Answer (score 13):

How about without recreating a new list, you can do by indexing:

```
>>> foo = ['1a','2b','3c','4d']
>>> for i in range(len(foo)):
...     print foo[-(i+1)]
...
4d
3c
2b
1a
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> length = len(foo)
>>> for i in range(length):
...     print foo[length-i-1]
...
4d
3c
2b
1a
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> l = ["a","b","c","d"]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> l
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

OR

```
>>> print l[::-1]
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 11):

I like the one-liner generator approach:

```python
((i, sequence[i]) for i in reversed(xrange(len(sequence))))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `list.reverse()` and then iterate as you normally would.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: For large lists, that's a waste of CPU time. Use `reversed` instead.

Answer (score 7):

for what ever it's worth you can do it like this too. very simple.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for x in xrange(len(a)):
    x += 1
    print a[-x]
```

Comment: You can also do `print a[-(x+1)]` and avoid reassigning the index in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

```
def reverse(spam):
    k = []
    for i in spam:
        k.insert(0,i)
    return "".join(k)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need the index and your list is small, the most readable way is to do `reversed(list(enumerate(your_list)))` like the accepted answer says. But this creates a copy of your list, so if your list is taking up a large portion of your memory you'll have to subtract the index returned by `enumerate(reversed())` from `len()-1`.

If you just need to do it once:

```
a = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']

for index, value in enumerate(reversed(a)):
    index = len(a)-1 - index

    do_something(index, value)
```

or if you need to do this multiple times you should use a generator:

```
def enumerate_reversed(lyst):
    for index, value in enumerate(reversed(lyst)):
        index = len(lyst)-1 - index
        yield index, value

for index, value in enumerate_reversed(a):
    do_something(index, value)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming task is to find last element that satisfies some condition in a list (i.e. first when looking backwards), I'm getting following numbers.

Python 2:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat('for i in xrange(len(xs)-1,-1,-1):\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
4.6937971115112305
>>> min(timeit.repeat('for i in reversed(xrange(0, len(xs))):\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
4.809093952178955
>>> min(timeit.repeat('for i, x in enumerate(reversed(xs), 1):\n    if 128 == x: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
4.931743860244751
>>> min(timeit.repeat('for i, x in enumerate(xs[::-1]):\n    if 128 == x: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
5.548468112945557
>>> min(timeit.repeat('for i in xrange(len(xs), 0, -1):\n    if 128 == xs[i - 1]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
6.286104917526245
>>> min(timeit.repeat('i = len(xs)\nwhile 0 < i:\n    i -= 1\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', repeat=8))
8.384078979492188
```

So, the ugliest option `xrange(len(xs)-1,-1,-1)` is the fastest.

Python 3 (different machine):

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(len(xs)-1,-1,-1):\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
4.48873088900001
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in reversed(range(0, len(xs))):\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
4.540959084000008
>>> timeit.timeit('for i, x in enumerate(reversed(xs), 1):\n    if 128 == x: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
1.9069805409999958
>>> timeit.timeit('for i, x in enumerate(xs[::-1]):\n    if 128 == x: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
2.960720073999994
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(len(xs), 0, -1):\n    if 128 == xs[i - 1]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
5.316207007999992
>>> timeit.timeit('i = len(xs)\nwhile 0 < i:\n    i -= 1\n    if 128 == xs[i]: break', setup='xs, n = range(256), 0', number=400000)
5.802550058999998
```

Here, `enumerate(reversed(xs), 1)` is the fastest.

Comment: What version of Python is this? Because range still does the job of xrange in 3.6

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the index being negative, you can do:

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...     print(~i, a[~i]))
-1 baz
-2 bar
-3 foo
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the most elegant way is to transform `enumerate` and `reversed` using the following generator

```
(-(ri+1), val) for ri, val in enumerate(reversed(foo))
```

which generates a the reverse of the `enumerate` iterator

Example:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = [3,6,9]
[
    bar[i] - val
    for i, val in ((-(ri+1), val) for ri, val in enumerate(reversed(foo)))
]
```

Result:

```
[6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

the reverse function comes in handy here:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4]
myArray.reverse()
for x in myArray:
    print x
```

Comment: list.reverse() has no return value

Answer (score 2):

To use negative indices: start at -1 and step back by -1 at each iteration.

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> for i in range(-1, -1*(len(a)+1), -1):
...     print i, a[i]
... 
-1 baz
-2 bar
-3 foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `while` loop:

```
i = len(collection)-1
while i>=0:
    value = collection[i]
    index = i
    i-=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative index in an ordinary for loop:

```
>>> collection = ["ham", "spam", "eggs", "baked beans"]
>>> for i in range(1, len(collection) + 1):
...     print(collection[-i])
... 
baked beans
eggs
spam
ham
```

To access the index as though you were iterating forward over a reversed copy of the collection, use `i - 1`:

```
>>> for i in range(1, len(collection) + 1):
...     print(i-1, collection[-i])
... 
0 baked beans
1 eggs
2 spam
3 ham
```

To access the original, un-reversed index, use `len(collection) - i`:

```
>>> for i in range(1, len(collection) + 1):
...     print(len(collection)-i, collection[-i])
... 
3 baked beans
2 eggs
1 spam
0 ham
```

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner in python, I found this way more easy to understand and reverses a list.

> say numlst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

> for i in range(len(numlst)-1,-1,-1):

```
ie., for i in range(3,-1,-1), where 3 is length of list minus 1,
second -1 means list starts from last element and 
third -1 signifies it will traverse in reverse order.
```

> print( numlst[ i ] )

> o/p = 4, 3, 2, 1

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good, but if you want to do as 
**List comprehension style**

```
collection = ['a','b','c']
[item for item in reversed( collection ) ]
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as reversed(collection)? Adding the list comprehension does nothing, except unnecessary computation. It is like writing a = [item for item in [1, 2, 3]] vs a = [1, 2, 3].

Answer (score 1):

```
input_list = ['foo','bar','baz']
for i in range(-1,-len(input_list)-1,-1)
    print(input_list[i])
```

i think this one is also simple way to do  it... read from end and keep decrementing till the length of list, since we never execute the "end" index hence added -1 also

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why the obvious choice did not pop up so far:

If `reversed()` is not working because you have a generator (as the case with `enumerate()`), just use `sorted()`:

```py
>>> l = list( 'abcdef' )
>>> sorted( enumerate(l), reverse=True )
[(5, 'f'), (4, 'e'), (3, 'd'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way :

```
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for i in reversed(range(0, n)):
    print("%d %d" %(i, arr[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a generator:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
len_li = len(li)
gen = (len_li-1-i for i in range(len_li))
```

finally:

```
for i in gen:
    print(li[i])
```

hope this help you.