# How can I want a direction of the counter to move the opposite in python?

Tags: python

I want the iterator to move the opposite way, which it moves from the biggest value to the smallest value. How can I do achieve this?  I have to give up this convenient way?

Comment: iterating over a list from end to start?

Comment: What are you talking about? Please give some example code!

Comment: I guess the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most iterables can be traversed in reverse by using the slice mechanism `[::-1]`.

```
s = "asdf"
for c in s[::-1]:
    print c

l = range(5):
for i in l[::-1]:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a for loop, you can do

```
for i in range(start, end, counter)
```

so if you wanted to iterate from 10 to 0, you would do

```
for i in range(10, -1, -1)
```

Remember that the `end` in the for loop is exclusive.