# Reverse list using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    new_list.insert(i,my_list[-1])
    my_list.pop(-1)
```

I used the above code to reverse a list but I was wondering why is the range(len(my_list)) necessary, more specifically, why doesn't it work if I simply put "for i in my_list:"?

Comment: `range(len(my_list))` return index list [0,1,2,3,4] instead of original list [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Why do you think it *should* work with `for i in my_list`?

Comment: Because they're different code, they (often) have different behavior. What do you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traverse a list in reverse order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
#use list slicing 
a = [123,122,56,754,56]
print(a[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

List can be reversed using for loop as follows:

```
>>> def reverse_list(nums):
...     # Traverse [n-1, -1) , in the opposite direction.
...     for i in range(len(nums)-1, -1, -1):
...         yield nums[i]
...
>>>
>>> print list(reverse_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Checkout this link on [Python List Reversal](https://pysnacks.com/python-tutorials/how-reverse-python-lists-in-place-slicing-reversed/#common-list-reversal-problems) for more details

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
new_list=[]

for item in my_list:
    new_list.insert(0, item)
    # or:
    # new_list = [item] + new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rev_lst(lst1, lst2):

    new_lst = [n for n in range(len(lst1)) if lst1[::-1]==lst2]
    return True
```

Could this be correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way would be:**

```
list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]


for i in range(len(list1)-1,-1,-1):

    print(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,2,3,400]
res = []

for i in lst:
    # Entering elements using backward index (pos, element)
    res.insert(-i, i)

print(res)
# Outputs [400, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
t = len(l) # ======>5 
for n in range(t-1,-1,-1):  # t-1 is 4 , -1 means 0 , decrement by-1 
    print(l[n])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful, of better quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.