# How can I use enumerate to count backwards?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Assume this is my list. Where `for i, letter in enumerate(letters)` would be:

```
0, a
1, b
2, c
```

How can I instead make it enumerate backwards, as:

```
2, a
1, b
0, c
```

Comment: Try: `for i, letter in reversed(list(enumerate(reversed(letters))))`

Comment: @davedwards Linked answer does not output exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @VivekPabani, true that! thanks Vivek ;-)

Comment: You could write your own function; `enumerate` is literally just 4 lines of code in python. Tweaking it a bit should do the job - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, letter in reversed(list(enumerate(reversed(letters)))):
    print(i, letter)
```

Output:

```
2 a
1 b
0 c
```

Comment: This answer has `O(n)` space complexity since `list()` creates a new list from the generator returned by `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 20):

This is a great solution and works perfectly:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
for idx, item in enumerate(items, start=-len(items)):
    print(f"reverse index for {item}: {abs(idx)}")
```

Here is the **OUTPUT** of the above snippet:

```
reverse index for a: 7
reverse index for b: 6
reverse index for c: 5
reverse index for d: 4
reverse index for e: 3
reverse index for f: 2
reverse index for g: 1
```

Here is what happening in above snippet:

- `enumerate`'s `start` arg is given a negative value.
- `enumerate` always takes a step forward.
- Finally we use `abs` on `idx` to find absolute value, which is always positive.
- If you want to start indexing from zero then use `-len(items) + 1` to fix **off-by-one error**

Comment: This is way more understandable and realistic than the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd use `-1 * idx` instead of calls to `abs()`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
l = len(letters)
for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    print(l-i, letters)
```

Comment: IMO this is better than negative indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make a reverse list first then you may use `enumerate()`

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
letters.reverse()
for i, letter in enumerate(letters)
```

Answer (score 1):

The zip function creates a list of element-wise pairs for two parameter lists.

```
list(zip([i for i in range(len(letters))][::-1], letters))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i, letter in zip(range(len(letters)-1, -1, -1), letters):
    print(i, letter)
```

prints

```
2 a
1 b
0 c
```

Taken from answer in a similar question: [Traverse a list in reverse order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: size - index - 1

I'll assume the question you are asking is whether or not you can have the index be reversed while the item is the same, for example, the a has the ordering number of 2 when it actually has an index of 0.

To calculate this, consider that each element in your array or list wants to have the index of the item with the same "distance" (index wise) from the end of the collection. Calculating this gives you size - index.

However, many programming languages start arrays with an index of 0. Due to this, we would need to subtract 1 in order to make the indices correspond properly. Consider our last element, with an index of size - 1. In our original equation, we would get size - (size - 1), which is equal to size - size + 1, which is equal to 1. Therefore, we need to subtract 1.

Final equation (for each element): size - index - 1

Answer (score 0):

We can define utility function (in **Python3.3+**)

```
from itertools import count


def enumerate_ext(iterable, start=0, step=1):
    indices = count(start, step)
    yield from zip(indices, iterable)
```

and use it directly like

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, letter in enumerate_ext(letters,
                                   start=len(letters) - 1,
                                   step=-1):
    print(index, letter)
```

or write helper

```
def reverse_enumerate(sequence):
    yield from enumerate_ext(sequence,
                             start=len(sequence) - 1,
                             step=-1)
```

and use it like

```
for index, letter in reverse_enumerate(letters):
    print(index, letter)
```