# My function doesn't work(works but gives wrong answer)

Tags: python

I m trying to have this result:
[5,4,8]

but I m getting this: []

```
listA = [4,1,8,4,5]
listB = [5,6,1,8,4,5]

class Solution(object):
    
    def getIntersectionNode(listA,listB):
        de=[]
        for i in range(-1,-len(listB)): 
            for j in range(-1,-len(listB)):
                
                if listA[i] == listB[i]:de.append(listA[-1])
                
                elif listA[-1] != listB[-1]: print("null")  
                                          
                
        return de
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Why did you use negative numbers in `range`? Presumably those are empty ranges.

Comment: The variable `j` isn't used, this is probably a typo.

Comment: You shouldn't get any result because you never create an instance of the class.

Comment: I need to start from the end

Comment: @MA To start from the end use `range(len(listB) - 1, -1, -1)`

Comment: yes it is typing mistake normally I used the j

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traverse a list in reverse order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)

Comment: it still empty list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection

Comment: @MA, you don't need to start from the end. The problem you try to solve is the problem #160 from leetcode, https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/. You asked to find the intersection of **linked** lists, not built-in python lists

Comment: range(-1,len(listA), - 1)
range(-1,len(listB), - 1)this is the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to worry about duplicates:

```
listA = [4,1,8,4,5]
listB = [5,6,1,8,4,5]

class Solution(object):
    
    def getIntersectionNode(listA,listB):
        de=list(set(listA) & set(listB))
             
        return de   
print(Solution.getIntersectionNode(listA,listB))
```

Comment: it has to start from end of the list and must stop when it differs(in this case it is just 5,4,8)

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is not [8, 1, 4, 5]?

If what you want is the intersection, you could use sets to achieve that easily:

```
list(set(listA).intersection(set(listB)))
```