# Python} Reversing List Without Using String Method

Tags: python-3.x

How should I write the code with the following problem?

Implement the function reverse_print(lst) that prints out the contents of the given list ‘lst’
in reverse order. For example, given a list [3, 6, 2, 1], the output should be 1, 2, 6, 3 (vertical
printout allowed). For this code, you are only allowed to use a single for-loop. ****Without String Method****

Also Not using Print[::-1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traverse a list in reverse order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not allowed to just call [`list.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) you can use `range` with a negative step to iterate the list in reverse order:

```
def reverse_print(lst):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        out.append(lst[i])
    print(*out, sep=", ")


inp = [1, 2, 3, 4]
reverse_print(inp)
```

Output: `4, 3, 2, 1`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
def reverse_print(lst):
    rev = [lst[abs(i-l)-1] for i in range(l)]
    return rev
lst = [3,6,2,1]
l = len(lst)
print(reverse_print(lst))
```