# How to print a list in a reversed order using only one for loop in python?

Tags: python, list

I have to define a function that prints out the list in reversed order. I'm not allowed to use str(), reversed(), .reverse or slicing method, and I must use only 1 for in loop. It's just about printing it reversed so the output printed vertically doesn't matter. I'm so lost please help :(

Comment: Why don't you use a loop over the indices from the last one in the list down to 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) (this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27401625)

Comment: Sorry, somehow I thought you were asking about a string, not a list, but the answer is much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`lst` is the list you want to reverse):

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(*(lst[len(lst) - idx - 1] for idx in range(len(lst))))
```

The previous code prints

```
4 3 2 1 0
```